# Excel row and colum value match

Tags: excel

can I use excel to select a range of values and sum them together based on the header of the column and the rows have certain values for example I want to find the sum of the cells from column(Station_Count  A02) but I only want the sum of the all the values for the range that starts with 6 the eg (6:30-6:55)  and so forth tried using index match but I'm missing something in the formula to grab the correct ranges.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try with SUMIFS with multiple criteria.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b